# How to find document by parts of ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, objectid

For some reason I use MongoDB native ObjectId as primary key for ticket identification number for my application. Is it possible to search documents with ObjectId parts?

For example: I have documents:

```
[
    {_id: ObjectId("577f8e6537e4a676203c056a")},
    {_id: ObjectId("577f8ee437e4a676203c0577")},
    {_id: ObjectId("577f8f3d717b6fdd22a1684c")}
]
```

And I want to query it by its `_id` contains "0577" so that it returns

```
 {_id: ObjectId("577f8ee437e4a676203c0577")}
```

I have tried regex before. It returned `[]`

```
db.transaction.find({_id: /0577/i}) ---> return 0
db.transaction.find({_id: {$regex: /0577/, $options: "i"}}) ---> return 0
```

Comment: The following post may give you more insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677655/find-a-mongodb-document-using-a-partial-id-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** like this:

```
db.transaction.find({ $where: "this._id.str.match(/.*0577/)" })
```