# How to query in mongodb with condition as regex matching ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

For some reason, I need to look up a collection with its entry ObjectId field. For example, how should I put up a query dictionary in the find() method, so that I get all entry with hex ObjectId matching '5c.*'.

```
> db.demoCommentCollection.find()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7fec06d2ea12b0cdc7a490"),
        "comment" : "Hi, I'm Al and I love Object Rocket and I love comments."
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4db1ec06d2ea12b0cdc7a491"),
        "comment" : "This is Cameron. I enjoyed reading your Object Rocket tutorials."
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7fec06d2ea12b0cdc7a492"),
        "userId" : 2,
        "comment" : "I'm Betty. This is my first comment on the site."
}
> db.demoCommentCollection.find({/* some query dict to query objectid hex start with '5c' */})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7fec06d2ea12b0cdc7a492"),
        "comment" : "I'm Betty. This is my first comment on the site."
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7fec06d2ea12b0cdc7a490"),
        "comment" : "Hi, I'm Al and I love Object Rocket and I love comments."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [How to find document by parts of ObjectId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277495/how-to-find-document-by-parts-of-objectid) you can use `$where` in pymongo.

```
db.mycollection.find({'$where': 'this._id.str.match(/^5c/)'})
```

Comment: Does it have injection risk?

Comment: Certainly it is a higher risk, yes.